# A code which copies data from a range in one tab to another, however every time the code is run it copies the data the row below. Excel VBA question

Tags: vba, copy, row, paste

My data range needs to be copied from one tab to another. The key to this is it needs to paste the information in the data range into a new row, even if the information is the same. So each time it is run a new row will be populated. Another key here is the row data range consists of criteria, depending on the value of criteria the code will decide which tab to copy into.

I was able to create the code to copy but without if statement and it copies into the same row each time

if Cell E3 = "Revenue" then copy into Revenue worksheet, if not then copy into Cost worksheet.
Each time code is run, the data will be copied into the last unoccupied row available in that worksheet

Answer (score 0):

If I understood You right, this should work:

```
Sub copy2sheet()

Dim cond As String
Dim lastRow As Integer

With Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    'taking name of the sheet from "E3"
    cond = .Range("E3").Value 

    'checking last filled row in sheet we gonna copy data
    lastRow = Sheets(cond).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    'copy data starting from "A1" to every cell is close to - CurrentRegion
    'a paste it into first empty cell in column "A"
    '.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets(cond).Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
    .Range("E3:H3").Copy Sheets(cond).Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: i do need a part of the code above which sends data to another tab in a empty row each time the code is run. this code needs to take account of the value cell E3 to determine which tab to send data to.

Comment: Added some comments to code to make it clear for You :)

Comment: Thanks. The code does not copy the data from range E3:H3 in my Input worksheet to my Revenue or cost worksheet. The data in range E3:H3 should be copied in revenue if cell E3 = Revenue and if it is not it should be copied into cost worksheet.

Comment: I just change the range for your E3:H3 :)

Comment: i only have one issue if the data needs to be sent to the tab from column b not a, it does not work the same as before

Comment: .Range("E3:H3").Copy Sheets(cond).Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
change that "A" to "B" if You need

Comment: I have on more issue - i need the range to work from E3:H13, with the code being able to differentiate between cost and revenue, still sending them to the correct tabs

Comment: just change .Range("E3:H3") to .Range("E3:H13"), as long as You are using code from above it is sending to the tabs specified in E3 cell from first tab :)

Comment: Yes but it does not work the same way when i change it. The orignial code will send the information in the range into new rows in the tab, but the change just copies it into the same row everytime i run the code

Comment: so i think the problem is E3 needs to change to E3:E13 but when i do this it brings error message "run time error '13 Type mismatch

Comment: do You have --> lastRow + 1) <--- in your code (last row of code above)?

Comment: Yes i do should i keep this?

Comment: I was just making myself sure, yes keep this, because it should move your selection to next empty cell in tab where code is pasting data.

Comment: The problem can appear when data, which macro is copying, is not fully filled in column E, probly 'lastRow' variable is counting less then 13 and its not pasting as You expect. Try to change 
lastRow = Sheets(cond).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
that number '1' to other number of column where will be no empty column